# SSIS: Control Flow Task Skipped

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm writing an SSIS package that is supposed to import flat files into a database then move them to another folder when done.

The flat files are in a bunch of sub folders so I'm using a Foreach Loop Container to find the files. In the Foreach Loop, I have a script task that compares the first line of the file to the expected column headings format. If it matches, then it moves on to the Data Flow Task, which transforms and loads the data into the database. After the Data Flow Task, there is an Expression Task to calculate the destination file path and then a File System Task to move the file.

The thing is, it never gets past the Data Flow Task. The package transforms and imports the files fine but after the Data Flow Task, the loop moves on to the next iteration. I put a breakpoint on the OnPreExecute event of the Expression Task but it never gets there and there are no errors. Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: old thread, but this could be a access issue or file system is not able to find the file mentioned. Were able to resolve it?